# Custom messages on couple regexp test fails

Tags: javascript, regex

Can't figure out how to show custom messages on password test regexp.

On submition I have next regexps thats works fine:

```
[a-zA-Z]{1,5}    -> min 6 or symbols. must contain digits
[0-9]{1,5}       -> min 6 or symbols. must contain letters
```

It's really strange, but next one:

```
[^\n]{6,}        -> min 6 or more symbols (means that having letters and digits)
```

And if I try to substitute this with:

```
[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5}
```

It doesn't works.

So and when I use:

```
[a-zA-Z]{6,}     -> digit is needed (we have 6 symbols)
[0-9]{6,}        -> letter is needed (we have 6 symbols)
```

They doesn't passes too.

Comment: I didn't understand your question . [a-z]{1,5} means letter count ranges from 1 to 5 and not  6 to more . Can you give your expected input and output?

Comment: I've changed in post. If I write "abc" it should pass with [a-zA-Z]{1,5} and print "min 6 or symbols. must contain digits".

Comment: Which programming language you are using ?

Comment: Great question!) JavaScript.

Comment: Why don't you use some if/else cases, one for length, one to check for presence/absence of digits, another for letters?

Comment: Really! I think it would best solution!

Comment: Just that strange case with [^\n] have distrubed me...

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code:

```
    var ar=[/[a-zA-Z]{1,5}/,/[a-zA-Z]{6,}/,/[0-9]{6,}/,/[^\n]{6,}/];
    var msg=["min 6 or symbols. must contain digits",
             "min 6 or more symbols (means that having letters and digits)",
             "digit is needed (we have 6 symbols)",
            "letter is needed (we have 6 symbols)",
            "min 6 or symbols. must contain digits"];
    var line="123456";
    for(i=0;i<ar.length;i++){ 
             if(ar[i].test(line))
               {  alert(msg[i]);
                     break;
               }

}
```

**[FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/SujithPS/LuP3J/1/)**